# Linking with x86 shared library on Linux x64

Tags: linux, linker, 64-bit, x86-64

I'm trying to link with x86 shared library on x64 Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal but I get the following message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./bin/libshared.so when searching for -lshared
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lshared
```

Some details:
The shared library name is libshared.so
The shared library is build on x86 OS.
I have installed lib32stdc++6.
The makefile looks like this:

```
test: main.o
    g++ -mi386linux -L./bin -lshared main.o -o test

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -m32 -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
After changing -mi386linux flag to -m32 I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lshared  
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

running locate I found libstdc++.so in the following places:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/libstdc++.so  
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6  
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
```

Comment: can you add output of `file -k ./bin/libshared.so main.o`?

Comment: @Ohad, did you see osgx's question? Please paste the output of that command.

Comment: Oops missed that remark thanks you @bdonlan for the reminder. What solved the problem in using -m32 and installing multilib. BTW the output of file -k is "main.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped" I'll remember that command next time I'll encounter such problems so thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `-mi386linux` is supposed to be about, but if you replace it by `-m32` on the link line then I suspect this will work.

Comment: Thanks, this led to a different error see my edit to the question. The output is a bit different so maybe it can lead to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use "-m32", and definitely put "-L/usr/lib32" as early as possible in your build command.